# Page.RouteData.Values["parameter"] not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I created a new Web Forms (ASP.NET 4.5) project and I'm trying to get URL routing to work.

`RouteConfig.cs` looks like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("surveyhome", "survey/home", "~/Survey.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("surveyquestions", "survey/questions/{q}", "~/Survey.aspx");
```

I have a link that looks like this:

```
<a href="/survey/questions/1">1</a>
```

It correctly loads the `Survey.aspx` page, so I know it's partly working, but this code (in the codebehind of that page) doesn't work:

```
if (Page.RouteData.Values["q"] != null)
{
    // do something
}
```

It's always null. Why?

Comment: What is 'q' supposed to represent?

Comment: Where are you setting it?  You may want to post more of the relevant code.

Comment: Could you tell me if RouteData have any values in this case?

Comment: Debugging tells me that RouteData has 0 Values. I'm not actively trying to figure out why this is not working on my side, but it still baffles me because theoretically this should work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26151214/1942551

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code, and no problems for me on ASP.NET 4.0.

Try defining default values, like

```
routes.MapPageRoute("surveyquestions",
    "survey/questions/{q}", "~/Survey.aspx",
    false,
    new RouteValueDictionary 
        { { "q", String.Empty } });
```

Did that resolve your problem?

Comment: Nope, still null. Baffled by why it works your side but not my side.

Comment: May be you are missing some configuration, have you added the RegisterRoute Method in Global.asax's App_Start?
Also check if you are missing anything in web.config

Answer (score 1):

First of all check if it contains the key in your case you can achive this with this line of code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("q"))
        {
            if (Page.RouteData.Values["q"] != null) 
            {
                Context.Response.Write(Page.RouteData.Values["q"]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Have you cheked that it is the right route .....????

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the UrlRoutingHandler and UrlRoutingModule being registered to IIS in your Web.config are the 4.0 version, and not the 3.5 version. This is the only thing that I can think of which would allow routing to work but your parameters to not map.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem and I got this resolved by adding following under the **configuration** section of web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```