# Page.RouteData.Values are empty for one page but not another

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, friendly-url

I have Routing working in ASP.NET c# WebForms using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls but **not** for all pages.

Here is an example:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("List/{Location}/{ZipCode}/", "List/{Location}/{ZipCode}/", "~/List.aspx");
```

On the above mentioned page (List.aspx) in the page_load there are no values.count in the Page.RouteData.

```
Page.RouteData.Values.Count == 0
```

I have another page in the same site with this info matched to it:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("{Location}/{ZipCode}/{Name}/{LocID}/{ID}/{Code}/", "{Location}/{ZipCode}/{Name}/{LocID}/{ID}/{Code}/", "~/place.aspx");
```

This page (place.aspx) always shows the correct count of Routes.

While on the List page in debug mode I checked the querystring and location and the ZipCode were there.

So, what might cause Page.RouteData to not show in one page but be available in another?

Comment: Still having this issue. I went on to use querystring (YUK!) months ago. Today I decided to do another search on google, as I came upon this issue again in the system. I found this thread and I was reading it thinking "WOW same issue as me!" Then I looked and it was my post!

Not sure if I could be more specific about the problem. If I click a link that sends me to a page it looks to be working. But not the page_load.

Comment: See my answer in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46365650/14263

Answer (score 9):

I am pretty new to url routing, but I think I ran into a similar problem and also found the solution. Have you tried:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("ListDetails/{Location}/{ZipCode}/", "ListDetails/{Location}/{ZipCode}/", "~/List.aspx");
```

instead of

```
routes.MapPageRoute("List/{Location}/{ZipCode}/", "List/{Location}/{ZipCode}/", "~/List.aspx");
```

?

In my case I had:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "ImageDelete",
    "Admin/Images/Delete/{nameToKill}",
    "~/Admin/Images.aspx"
);
```

which showed Page.RouteData.Values always empty.

When I changed it to

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "ImageDelete",
    "Admin/Image/Delete/{nameToKill}", // mind the missing 's'
    "~/Admin/Images.aspx"
);
```

it worked!

I think the route may not start with the URL of a site that actually exists.

Comment: Wow, thanks for telling me something useful that should be in the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551(v=vs.100).aspx