# RouteData.Values stays Empty

Tags: c#, web, routes

My Code for the Route looks like this:

```
 RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("IDP", "Person/{IDP}", "~/Person.aspx")
```

And now i want to get the Data on a Form, normally it works like this:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Page.RouteData.Values["IDP"]);
```

But everytime i try to get the Data from the Route e.g.: `http://PC-81/SkillDatenbank/Person/1`
I get no Data from the Value (it is empty!)

I am using ASP.Net 4.5 with Web Forms.
Edit: I made an new Project and tested and it didnt work either
What am i Doing wrong? in the Last Project it did work like this :(
Can you help me?

Comment: Where do you assign your `id` variable? On `Page_Load`, afterwards, before?

Comment: Right in the page_Load on the beginning Edit: i did the method in a button and tried it then. But still in `code`Page.RouteData.Values["ID"]; is nothing at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code has worked for me, I have moved additional routes to top of the function.

Also, in my case RedirectMode is off because I'm using Jquery in my code and inorder to make a Webmethod work, I have turned off RedirectMode.

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     /* ... additional routes */
    routes.MapPageRoute("","Person/{IDP}", "~/Person.aspx");

    var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
    settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);

}
```

Comment: Yes - calling MapPageRoute **before** calling EnableFriendlyRoutes() solved it for me.
Calling MapPageRoute **after** resulted in Page.RouteData.Values[] being empty

Answer (score 3):

Your problem ist probably located in your Routing table. I have created a WebForms project to test this out.

Open up your `Global.asax` (or whereever you store your RouteConfig; default is App_Start/RouteConfig.cs) and check your RegisterRoutes method. Add the following line to it, if it isn't already present.

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
    settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);

    /* ... additional routes */
    routes.MapPageRoute("","Person/{IDP}", "~/Person.aspx");
}
```

In your `Application_Start` there should be a line like this, if you use the default configuration with in the App_Start folder: `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`

If you defined your routes in your global.asax.cs it is just `RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`

If you now access your Page via `http://PC-81/SkillDatenbank/Person/1` the RouteData dictionary will contain 1 set of data, like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot this has worked! anyway it's weird that the other way worked in my other project at all, but i am fine with that!

Comment: I've done exactly this and still get values.count = 0

Comment: answer to my issue is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746022/page-routedata-values-are-empty-for-one-page-but-not-another

You can't use a routing name that is an actual page name

Comment: Not entirely true, see the other answer for the solution. But it kinda solves the issue as well.